# create column based on two matching

Tags: r, string-matching, col

I am working in R. So I need to create a new column in data frame `A` with values from data frame `B`.

The values in each row should be because the entries in a col from data frame `A` are the same from the entries in a col from data frame `B`.

For example, if I have a data frame `A`

```
/Users/adrianapero/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-06-23 at 7.11.44 AM.png
```

and a data frame `B`

```
/Users/adrianapero/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-06-23 at 7.11.56 AM.png
```

And I want `A` to have the column `avg` like this

```
/Users/adrianapero/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-06-23 at 7.13.04 AM.png
```

I have used the code

```
a$avg <- ifelse(a$v1 %in% b$v2, b$avg, NA)
```

When I used this on a much larger data.frame, it did not fill in the values in data frame `A` for all of the variables that occurred in data.frame `B`, and those that were filled in were not always correct.

Comment: Change to `b$avg` to `b$v2` (or even `a$v2`)

Answer (score 0):

a$avg <- ifelse(a$v1==b$v2, b$avg, NA)